# MC24C08 EEPROM Write Cycles

Tags: eeprom

What is the MC24C08 maximum write cycle count for a given bit or for a given byte? It doesn't say so on the datasheet, and I get conflicting answers when I look up this question for other EEPROMs (made by different manufacturers).

Comment: Which specific STM32 model you mean? Generally they don't even have EEPROM.

Comment: M24C08 line of EEPROM.

Comment: It says right on the datasheet, page 23.

Comment: Which exact chip model, which manufacturer, which datasheet?

Comment: @Hearth: It also says right on page 1 of the datasheet.... but you're correct that page 23 shows details, including the voltage and temperature conditions under which the front-page performance claim is made.

Comment: @Dan: You got the part number correct in your comment, but both mentions in the question still have an extra `C` thrown in.  Use the Edit link under your question to correct important details like that.

Comment: Given that the front page of the datasheet makes a claim of the number of cycles, but your question mentions "for a bit" and "for a byte", I assume you are asking a more complex question, perhaps similar to the one here (only for a different EEPROM): [EEPROM endurance and page size](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/9351/6680)

Comment: and also https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/262004/1743

Comment: @BenVoigt I missed it on the first page, apparently!

Comment: @BenVoigt that is correct. I am wondering if the write cycle endurance is per bit or per byte. I did see that page. However, I am not sure if that went for all EEPROM without qualification, or if some datasheets measured per byte vs. others per bit.

Comment: I'm assuming you're using MC24C08 from st.com -- they have an [applications note AN4653](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/an4653-cycling-endurance-and-data-retention-of-high-density-eeprom-based-on-cmos-f8h-process-stmicroelectronics.pdf) about this topic, with graphs and their testing methodology. This kind of QA/appnote document isn't as easy to find as datasheets, but all reputable manufacturers have this kind of information published somewhere on their website. I had to go up to https://www.st.com/en/memories/standard-serial-eeprom.html#documentation to find this one.

Comment: @Dan: When you've seen a page which is an almost perfect answer to your question except for one issue (it's for a different family of EEPROM), it's really helpful to link that in your question to make sure everyone understands what you are asking.  And you still need to correct the part number in your question.

Answer (score -1):

As indicated in the application note linked by @MarkU, the write cycle endurance specified in the STM32 datasheet is per byte, not per bit.

EDIT: The application note in question is AN4653, which was linked to STM32's EEPROM MC24C08.

Comment: It was never going to be per bit, but whether it was per byte or per page was a reasonable question.

Comment: Also, please write your answer so that it is able to stand alone if all the comments are removed later.  It's good to refer to a comment in order to give credit to another user, but referring to it for the essential technical information is not correct; put the application note number, title, and link in your answer.

Comment: Hard to believe it would be per byte. At least other chip datasheets say page writes are possible, and memory is internally organized in pages of multiple bytes, and endurance is identical for Byte and Page writes. Microchip 24C08B datasheet says bytes are temporarily stored in a page buffer. I'd say it's more likely to be per page, which is why writes should be made in pages instead of single contiguous bytes.

Comment: I know that this EEPROM supports both byte write and page write.

Comment: Yes but even if you write a single byte the chip still needs to do a page write for all writes.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean.