# In case of power failure, how the ROM will store the data?

Tags: rom

How the ROM Memory will hold the data even in the case of power failure?

Answer (score 5):

Most rewritable ROM (a contradictio in terminis) today is **Flash**. It stores the data as an electrical charge on a floating gate, which is embedded in Silicon dioxide, one of the best insulators there are. So the charge can't leak away from the gate, and can be held for tens of years. If you switch the power off the charge will still be there.

If you don't need to change the data then for large volumes **mask-programmable ROM** may be chosen. An IC like a microcontroller has one or more interconnection layers to connect the transistors. In a mask-programmable ROM the mask defines which bits will be read as a `1`, and which as a `0`. They're part of the IC's hardware, and won't change when powered off.

*drxzl* mentions the ancient **Fusible-Link ROM**, but that's becoming rare because of its cost, and the low density. Flash costs about 1 dollar per gigabit, Fusible-Link will be a multiple of that. Though the technology isn't perfect (there's the fenomenon of link regrowth in nichrome fuses) it may still be used in some cases where high reliability is a premium.

**Further reading**
[Data retention on a microcontroller](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/16183/data-retention-on-a-microcontroller)

Comment: Hi steevnh , This is amazing,its really wothfull.     If possible can you share your knowledge on EEPROM,FLASH Memory,EPROM and different types of ROM

Comment: @Sachin - I added a link about Flash and EEPROM to my answer.

Comment: Rewritable ROM is not a contradiction in terms, if the system in which the memory will be installed cannot write to it.  After all, even diode ROM can be "written" if one gets out a soldering iron.

Answer (score 4):

The entire point of ROM is that the contents do not change, not even when the power supply is interrupted. So your ROM will be just fine after a power failure.

Note however that modern applications use mostly programmable non-volatile memory (NVRAM) such as flash or phase-change memory instead of "true" ROM. The contents of these memories will survive a power-cycle as well, but the can be re-programmed if needed.

Exactly how nonvolatile memory maintains the contents while unpowered depends on the technology used. For example, in the case of one time programmable anti-fuse based memory, the data is literally "burned" into the memory by blowing some very small fuses.

Comment: Its really  helpful sir

Answer (score 4):

> How the ROM Memory will hold the data even in the case of power failure?

It does it "by definition".
 If the technology used in a memory does this then it is a ROM.
 If it changes state when power is removed and / or  restored then it is NOT a ROM.

ie A ROM is simply a memory that by definition  uses a technology such that the state of memory "bits" does not change when depowered.

An example: A punchcard is a piece of light cardboard that has patterns of holes punched in it to describe data. That's a ROM. You would not expect the holes to vanish or more holes to appear when you "turned off the power".

**A card board ROM:** {[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punched_card)} Holes do not change when power is removed.

- An 80-column punched card of the type most widely used in the 20th century. Card size was 7 3⁄8 in × 3 1⁄4 in (187.325 mm × 82.55 mm). This example displays the 1964 EBCDIC character set, which added more special characters to earlier encodings.

[image]

A small part of a very long thick-paper ROM - a Painola roll. Holes correspond to notes and control instructions to the player piano. Holes do not change when power is removed.
[image]

http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fe/WelteHandnuancierung.jpg/220px-WelteHandnuancierung.jpg

[WIKIPEDIA - ROM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-only_memory)

[WIKIPEDIA - Diode Matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diode_matrix) - a diode ROM.

[WIKIPEDIA - ROM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-only_memory)

Answer (score 4):

Like out brains, digital memory could be classified in terms of short term, medium term and long term. The reliability and ruggedness of the memory depends on what environmental risks are present. This includes vibration, shock, thermal shock, gamma radiation for space equipment.

Like our brains they are ONLY as reliable as often as you test them. Otherwise how do you know for sure?

The choices of ROM material for electric, optical, magnetic, paper, plastic, metallic, electron spin orientation or simple charge layers trapped inside a flash ROM etc.etc.   Each choice depends on; cost per MB, capacity, reliability, and environmental tolerance limits. Oh did I say reliability?

But in the simplest sense, we all know the boot ROM's in our PC's but rarely get a chance to see the inside of them and how they are made.

A couple ROM's outside view.
[image][image]

ROM Inside View.
[image][image]

Deeper Inside the ROM view.
[image] 
OK that look's like the Disney version.

Even deeper inside a cell..
[image]

Just kidding. That's a metaphor for the bug in your program.

Deep down, where is my BOOT ROM really stored?
[image]
Still can't see it??

[image]
Woooah  what's that?  The new RFID chips have a 128-bit ROM for storing a unique 38 digit number, like their predecessor. Hitachi used semiconductor miniaturization technology and electron beams to write data on the chip substrates to achieve the new, smaller size. [image]
It's magnetic and very tiny.

I know you just wanted to know about the PC ROM.[image] Is that it? Well only if you wanted to slice it open and "peek n poke" at the memory cell for a forensic report.

Come on show me the memory!
[image]
Hey that looks like a multi-layer copper circuit board. Well pretty close. It's your ROM Chip and you can see the pads where gold wire is "µ-welded".

Now we're talking about ROM profile. What you mean lightbulb filament and Gold is in here?
[image]

Fortunately for chips, mag cores, punch tape, E-squared ROM, flash mem. and the computers they are connected to , a simple means of checking the contents exists.

It might use parity, and/or CRC. It may use ECC like simple Hamming code for single or multiple bit correction. Recent I2C flash memory which may suffer from very low yields if it were not for the ECC using Hamming code bits. If we did not have Chinese Remainder Theorem ECC inside Terabyte disk drives, our poor PCs would be dealing with "non-volatile" data errors all the time. The power of these  memory correction mechanisms does one bad thing. You lose visibility of how close to disaster when it fails to remember or catastrophic errors.

This may become more significant when Flash ROM's carry 16,32 or 64 bits per memory cell with data encoded like modem QAM voltages in a charge level. This will certainly bring new challenges to those developing the chips to provide consistent process improvements and determine all causes of degradation before releasing them to the field.  Take for example leaving a CD in the sun and all of sudden it warps a bit and you can no long read it.  Or a power surge flows past your power supply from a tiny  5kV lightning hit and over stresses all your power electronics rated for only 3kV.

THis is especially relevant for Flash ROMs which reduce in price and they squeeze more bits per cell using analog levels instead of binary states. So Hamming code 1bit correction is automatically applied to 8 pin serial flash chips and very complex ECC algorithms are used in Terrabyte Disk drives to make them appear "error free"... They are all Non-Volatile... Until thy fail....

Understanding the limits to volatility to each technology , whether it is optical, magnetic, charge layer, paper, cobalt-doped magnetic plastic, helps you appreciate the past, present and future technologies that can be used in a ROM application.

All *could be used* as ROM's by enabling the Write Protect signal, if it exists. (obviously punch cards do not have nor need this option)

Comment: ...what was your point?