# How often can an ATtiny85 be flashed?

Tags: attiny

I wonder how often I can flash an ATtiny85 before the EEPROM will give up.

**Solved**

Sometimes it is just on the first page of the [datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-2586-AVR-8-bit-Microcontroller-ATtiny25-ATtiny45-ATtiny85_Datasheet.pdf):

[image]

Comment: After  the ten-thousanth time...you might ask how long it *remains* flashed before leaking bits.

Comment: How long do you think it will remain flashed before leaking bits?

Comment: stackexchange has *at least* an 11-year memory: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/16183/data-retention-on-a-microcontroller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It reads on the first page of the data sheet.

EEPROM is specified for 100000 write/erase cycles.

It does not depend on how often you do it, no matter how fast or slow it still is 100000 write/erase cycles.

Comment: Oh so often, that I didn't expect!

Comment: Some caveats apply. The EEPROM page size is 4 bytes so if you write four bytes all four memory locations are erased and written four times.  Unless you mean the program flash. That's only 10000.

Comment: It seems that I might have meant the flash memory instead of the EEPROM. I use Arduino IDE to upload a simple sketch. To my shame, I don't know what the difference is yet.

Comment: Then you mean the program memory flash.

Comment: Then even 10,000 cycles should be reasonable. I have mistakenly assumed the limit would be way more less (about 50-100 cycles) and so thought it would be risky to flash it too often during development before I finish my project.